# Log and Report button is getting disabled in RIDE after executing test case

Tags: button, logging, report, robotframework, execution

i am running the test on VM client machine, sometimes when i run the tests it's got executed properly but the Log and Report buttons are getting disabled and i am able to find the Log path to open the log. But sometimes the Test won't stop even after completing the steps execution, the elapsed time is still running and when click Stop for 2 to 3 times the execution will stop and i didn't get any reports or logs for that test.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same error while running Selenium tests.  When this happens, open your task manager and check out your background processes. You might see there are multiple chromedriver.exe/geckodriver.exe processes running. This happens when you have not terminated your test case gracefully (in my case, not closing the browser) which leads to disabling of both Log and Report button. To fix this you will be needing to use

> **Browser Close**

keyword at the end of your test case. In short, graceful termination was missing in your test case.

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
sample_test
    # ->Perform Functionality<-

    # Graceful Termination
    s2l.Browser Close
```

This will kill the background webdriver processes. Now on the log and report button will be in enabled state each time you run the test.

Check out this response: [Log and Report buttons are disabled in RIDE](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/issues/1755)